# Why do we need mass in the energy conservation from Newtonian physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, energy-conservation, dimensional-analysis

We have a conservative force field $\vec{E}$. The conservation theorem can be expressed without mass as:

$$\frac{1}{2}v^2-\frac{1}{2}{u}^2=\int \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dS}.$$

The quantity $\frac{1}{2}v^2$ can be defined as the kinetic energy of an object moving with speed $v$. The change in this quantity would only depend on the start and end points of the object's path

What is the need to multiply both sides by $m$ in the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the dimension right, You have to multiphy the left-hand-side by $m$ and right-hand-side by charge $q$:

$$\frac{1}{2} m v^2-\frac{1}{2} m {u}^2= q\int  \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}.$$

or
$$\frac{1}{2} v^2-\frac{1}{2} {u}^2= \frac{q}{m} \int  \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}.$$

Comment: So would this not be needed if the force was gravity?

Comment: You still need $m$ to make the righr-hand-side to be dimension of force.

Comment: But the equation $\frac{1}{2} (v^2-u^2)=\int \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dS}$ would already be dimensionally correct if $\vec{E}$ is the gravitational field

Comment: Yes. If it is the gravitational filed, not gravitation force. The force and the field are dimensional different by a factor $m$.